# docker: Command "/bin/sh" not found

Tags: node.js, docker

```
ENV PORT=3000
ENV NODE_ENV=production
EXPOSE $PORT

WORKDIR $APP_DIR
COPY yarn.lock package.json $APP_DIR/
RUN ["/usr/local/bin/yarn"]

COPY . $APP_DIR
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/yarn", "run"]
CMD ['dev']
```

Was running this using this command

`docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 my-app:latest`

And the console outputs

`yarn run v0.17.9
error Command "/bin/sh" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.`

I expect `/usr/local/bin/yarn run dev` to be executed inside docker, am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try switching to double quotes, single quotes aren't valid for a json string:

```
CMD ["dev"]
```

Comment: Anything that isn't json gets turned into `/bin/sh -c "$@"`. You can see this happening if you run a `docker inspect` on your image after building it.

Comment: Thank you very much.. Almost got me frustrated